# Estimate Options Delta By Hand

Tags: options, volatility, greeks

Underlying = 100
K = 90

1 year Put at K is trading 5. What's the approximate delta of the put?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you don't have a black scholes pricer, or don't want to rely on a pricer... the following book contains many of the "rule of thumbs"  that you are seeking:

https://www.amazon.de/Calculate-Options-Prices-Their-Greeks-ebook/dp/B00WBJN75I/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1492818200&sr=8-2&keywords=ursone

Comment: That would be a good addition to the linked question.